# Sum of combination of items without repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider we have $A,B,C$.

What is the formula in combinatorics to get the value of 15 we have here for this special example:

$\{A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,BA,CA,CB,ABC,BCA,CBA,BAC,ACB,CAB\}$

but in the general case for $n$ items?

Comment: Interesting problem. Can you show your efforts?

Comment: this is [A007526](https://oeis.org/A007526)

Comment: @lulu What the hell is that! Never saw this in my life... LOL

Comment: You mean OEIS?  It's fantastically useful.  Here, I just worked out the answer for small $n$, typed in the sequence, and got the hit immediately.  It's not perfect, of course, but if that site doesn't present a useful closed formula for a sequence that's usually a reliable sign that there isn't one (known).

Comment: @lulu Yes i see that.... Thanks for your answer by the way!